# Techniques for load testing and baselining performance on a SharePoint site?

Tags: visual-studio, testing, load-testing

So far I have considered upgrading to Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate in order to get access to the testing tools.  I also looked at the Visual Studio Load Test Virtual User Pack 2010, but I'm not sure if this is an add on to Ultimate or if it will work with other versions of Visual Studio.

Can anyone recommend a good baselineing/load testing tool for SharePoint, or are the above my best options?